# What direction do you face to pray when in LA?

Tags: salat, masjid, mecca

The shortest distance between LA and Mecca would have a person facing nearly north.

In what direction do Muslims in LA face while praying? If it's east, should it be changed?

[image]

Comment: We face the direction as shown on the map. Not sure why you think it should be east. That only appears so on a flat projection.

Comment: Cool, cheers bud.